# Line chart issues - plot looks "funny" (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

I have a large dataframe (CO2_df) with many years for many countries, and tried to plot a graph with `ggplot2`. This graph will have 6 curves + an aggregate curve. However, my graph looks pretty "funny" and I have no idea why.

The data looks like this (excerpt):

```
       x     y          x1      x2      x4   x6
1553   1993  0.00000    CO2     Austria  6   6 - Other Sector
1554   2006  0.00000    CO2     Austria  6   6 - Other Sector
1555   2015  0.00000    CO2     Austria  6   6 - Other Sector
2243   1998  12.07760   CO2     Austria  5   5 - Waste management
2400   1992  11.12720   CO2     Austria  5   5 - Waste management
2401   1995  11.11040   CO2     Austria  5   5 - Waste management
2402   2006  10.26000   CO2     Austria  5   5 - Waste management
2489   1998  0.00000    CO2     Austria  6   6 - Other Sector
```

I have used this code:

```
ggplot(data=CO2_df, aes(x=x, y=y, group=x6, colour=x6)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Austria") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("C02 Emissions") +
  labs(colour = "Sectors")
scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")  

CO2_df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  mutate(sum.y = sum(y)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, group=x6, colour=x6)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Austria") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("C02 Emissions") +
  labs(colour = "Sectors")+
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")+
  geom_line(aes(y = sum.y), color = "black")
```

My questions

1) Why does it look like this and how can I solve it?
2) I have no idea why the value on the y axis are close to zero. They are not...
3) How can I add an entry to the legend for the aggregate line?

[image: this]

Thank you for any sort of help!

Nordsee

Comment: Can you use `dput()` and give us a subset of your data frame to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
  CO2_df %>%                            # data                 
  group_by(x,x6) %>%                    # group by
  summarise(y = sum(y)) %>%             # add the sum per group
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y)) +               # plot
  geom_line(aes(group=x6, fill=x6, color=x6))+
  # here you can put a summary line, like sum, or mean, and so on
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, na.rm = TRUE, color = 'black', geom ='line') +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Austria") +
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("C02 Emissions") +
  labs(colour = "Sectors")+
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2"))
```

[image]

With modified data, to see the right behaviour, I've put same years and very different values to understand:

```
   CO2_df <- read.table(text ="
x     y          x1      x2      x4   x6
1553   1993  20    CO2     'Austria'  6   '6 - Other Sector'
1554   1994  23    CO2     'Austria'  6   '6 - Other Sector'
1555   1995  43    CO2     'Austria'  6   '6 - Other Sector'
2243   1993  12.07760   CO2     'Austria'  5   '5 - Waste management'
2400   1994  11.12720   CO2     'Austria'  5   '5 - Waste management'
2401   1995  11.11040   CO2     'Austria'  5   '5 - Waste management'
2402   1996  10.26000   CO2     'Austria'  5   '5 - Waste management'
2489   1996  50    CO2     'Austria'  6   '6 - Other Sector'", header = T)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This does it! However, I just realised the true issue was that I forgot to tell the code that it should only select Austria as a country... Thanks again!